# Not able to see font-awesome icons on mobile version of the app

Tags: asp.net, font-awesome

I have added font-awesome files in the project and I have called it in the page that I want to view on mobile, but I am not able to see the icons.
I am using Opera Mobile Emulator to view the mobile version of the application.Please help.Thanks.

```
<link href="../Content/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../Content/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<span>
<i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span>
<asp:Label ID="lbl_USERNAME" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'CDN' Links

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
```